# Concrete and abstract definitions in Scala.js facades

Tags: scala.js

It's said in the [documentation](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) that

> In native JS types, all concrete definitions must have = js.native as body. Any other body will be handled as if it were = js.native, and a warning will be emitted. (In Scala.js 1.0.0, this will become an error.)

And that's correct. However I found that I can omit body at all (thus making definition abstract) and there is no warning and generated js seems to be the same as with `js.native` body.

So my question is: what's the difference between abstract definitions and concrete definitions with `js.native` body?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that an abstract definition is abstract, and, well, a concrete definition (with `= js.native`) is concrete, from Scala's type system point of view.

But then what? From the *use* site of the class or trait, is doesn't make a difference. This is similar to normal Scala (or Java): when using a method, it doesn't matter whether it is abstract or not.

So the real difference is on the definition site. In theory, choosing abstract or concrete boils down to this criterium:

- Does this method have an actual *implementation* in JavaScript code (not only a documented contract)? If yes, it should be concrete; if not, it should be abstract.

Practically and pragmatically, note that an abstract method can only appear in an abstract class or a trait, and must be implemented in a subclass/subtrait.

In terms of facade, in a native class, most methods should be concrete (if not all). That is because in JS, classes usually have concrete methods. In fact, *abstract* methods do not even exist in JS. The only reasonable case of defining an abstract method in a native class is if the "contract/documentation" of that class stipulates than a) it should be subclassed and b) subclasses should implement a particular method (not implemented in the superclass). This documented contract is as close as JS can get to abstract methods.

In JS *traits*, methods should usually be abstract (and the traits themselves be `@ScalaJSDefined` rather than `@js.native`). That is because traits/interfaces themselves do not even exist in JS. They only exist by their documented contract, which specifies what methods must/will be implemented by classes that satisfy this interface.

The only reasonable use case for concrete methods in (`@js.native`) JS traits is for DRYness. If several classes of a native API implement the same (large) set of methods, it can be reasonable to gather those methods in a native trait. In order not to have to repeat their definitions in all classes, they can be made concrete in the trait (if they were abstract, the classes would need to provided a concrete version to satisfy the contract). Note that such traits cannot be extended by non-native (`@ScalaJSDefined`) JS classes.

In the cases where you don't want to figure out the above "theoretical" criterium, use the following rule of thumb:

- Is the method in a native JS class? If yes, it is almost certainly concrete.
- Is it in a JS trait? If yes, it is almost certainly abstract (and the trait should be `@ScalaJSDefined`).